# Android setContentView ecnapsulation

Tags: android, android-activity, encapsulation, android-dialog

I need to make a singleton or static class to change localization of an app, it will have the following implementation

```
public static void changeLocale( Context context , int layoutID ,int pos )
{
    if ( currentLocale == pos)
        return;
    Locale locale;
    if (pos == 0)
        locale = new Locale("en");
    else
        locale = new Locale("ar");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,              context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    //setContentView(layoutID);
}
```

It will be called from either Activity or Dialog, my problem here is that `Context` doesn't have `setContentView()`, what interface or class shall I pass instead of context that would have `setContentView()`, one way to do this is passing an Object and have it to be cast into `Activity` or `Dialog` in try catch blocks, but I believe there is a better way to do this, thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set contentview when you change locale
this is an excert from : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

you only need to create a new layout for the specific locale called res/layout-localename/sameresourceinallotherfolders.xml

and it should change the content view accordingly, when you change the locale

> Design a flexible layout
>
> If you need to rearrange your layout to fit a certain language (for
>   example German with its long words), you can create an alternative
>   layout for that language (for example res/layout-de/main.xml).
>   However, doing this can make your application harder to maintain. It
>   is better to create a single layout that is more flexible.
>
> Another typical situation is a language that requires something
>   different in its layout. For example, you might have a contact form
>   that should include two name fields when the application runs in
>   Japanese, but three name fields when the application runs in some
>   other language. You could handle this in either of two ways:
>
> Create one layout with a field that you can programmatically enable or
>   disable, based on the language, or Have the main layout include
>   another layout that includes the changeable field. The second layout
>   can have different configurations for different languages. Avoid
>   creating more resource files and text strings than you need
>
> You probably do not need to create a locale-specific alternative for
>   every resource in your application. For example, the layout defined in
>   the res/layout/main.xml file might work in any locale, in which case
>   there would be no need to create any alternative layout files.
>
> Also, you might not need to create alternative text for every string.
>   For example, assume the following:
>
> Your application's default language is American English. Every string
>   that the application uses is defined, using American English
>   spellings, in res/values/strings.xml. For a few important phrases, you
>   want to provide British English spelling. You want these alternative
>   strings to be used when your application runs on a device in the
>   United Kingdom. To do this, you could create a small file called
>   res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml that includes only the strings that
>   should be different when the application runs in the U.K. For all the
>   rest of the strings, the application will fall back to the defaults
>   and use what is defined in res/values/strings.xml.
>
> Use the Android Context object for manual locale lookup
>
> You can look up the locale using the Context object that Android makes
>   available:
>
> String locale =
>   context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName();

Comment: I tried not setting contentview didn't work you MUST call setContentView(), but I always like official documentation qoutes :)

Comment: you need to setContentView once at the oncreate function - then if you change the locale, the contentview should change according to the locale